# Uniqueness of solution of microscopic PDE inhomogeneous neumann boundary condition

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fixed-point-theorems

The problem is as follows:
$u_k: \Omega_k \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$-div(A(x,\frac{x}{k})\nabla(u_k)) = f(u_k)$$ in $\Omega_k$
$$-A(x,\frac{x}{k})\nabla(u_k)\nu = -kg$$ on $\Gamma_k$
$$u_k=0$$ on the boundary of $\Omega$

For now, we can assume that $\Omega_k$ is a domain that is dependent on a factor $k$, $0<k<1$. We take $A$ to be elliptic and in $L^\inf$, $g,f$ are both continuous.

I have a theorem that says that if $f$ is Lipschitz-continuous for $L>0$ then, a solution of this problem will be unique (if $L$ is small enough).

I am not sure how to begin to show this. I am familiar with the Picard proof that uses Banach fixed point theorem, or just regular $w=u_1-u_2$ type of proofs, but I am not able to apply those ideas here.